# How to list all axes that exist in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, axes, multiple-axes

Quick general question I wonder if anyone has the answer to please.

Is there a way to get matplotlib to list all axes that currently exist?

I'm trying to write some general code for clearing all twinned axes in a subplot (but not clearing the whole figure). So in pseudocode, I'd like to do:

Creation code:

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
ax2a = ax2.twinx()
```

Code I'm stuck with:

```
my_axes = get_axes(subplot based on ax2)
for axis in my_axes:
    axis.cla()
```

All suggestions welcomed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [matplotlib get all axes that a given figure contains to apply some settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23848412/matplotlib-get-all-axes-that-a-given-figure-contains-to-apply-some-settings)

Comment: Provide [`get_shared_x_axes()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_shared_x_axes) and `get_shared_y_axes())` the functionality you need?